# How to feature detect for CSS custom properties?

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr, feature-detection, css-variables

Is there any way to detect whether a browser supports [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) (eg. `color: var(--primary)`)?

I need to write a script that behaves slightly differently in browsers that don't support custom properties, but I can't find any documented [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) tests, nor any information about the Javascript interface for accessing custom properties.

Would be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: No wonder this question seemed so familiar. A pox on me for answering a duplicate?

Comment: Ah, I did search for duplicates, but I was looking for "custom properties" (the official name, I believe), not "CSS variables".

Comment: Yeah - people call them CSS variables because it's more relatable, and partially also because the module is called "Custom Properties for Cascading Variables", which they kind of are.

Comment: Oh, yeah, it totally makes sense to refer to them as CSS variables. I do myself. Having an alternative name in common use just makes searching for info a bit more difficult!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can reliably use `CSS.supports()` in JavaScript or `@supports` in CSS to detect support for custom properties. Every version of every browser that supports [custom properties](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) also supports [this method of feature detection](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries).

```js
if (window.CSS && CSS.supports('color', 'var(--primary)')) {
  document.body.innerHTML = 'Supported';
}
```

```css
@supports (color: var(--primary)) {
  body {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

Notice that this does not require you to declare the `--primary` custom property, as by definition [every property whose name begins with `--` is considered valid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#defining-variables) for the purposes of parsing property declarations.

Comment: How wonderfully direct!

Comment: You may want to check if CSS.supports is defined before calling.

Comment: @jcubic: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Just in case anyone else wonders if `CSS` can be defined without `CSS.supports` being defined (thus, do you need to check for `CSS.supports` before calling it, or is checking for `window.CSS` sufficient?): the `CSS` global was introduced with `supports` being its initial rationale; all browsers with a `CSS` global have `CSS.supports`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave this as an example of how to approach this sort of thing when you don't have an alternative, but [BoltClock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38012166/157247) is the way to go in this case.

---

I expect you could define one and then check whether its value comes through to `getComputedStyle`. For instance, this shows `Supports custom props? true` on Chrome (which supports custom CSS properties) but `Supports custom props? false` on IE11 (which doesn't):

```js
function areCSSVarsSupported() {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.id = "test";
  document.body.appendChild(d);
  var pos = getComputedStyle(d).position;
  document.body.removeChild(d);
  return pos === "fixed";
}
console.log("Supports custom props? " + areCSSVarsSupported());
```

```css
:root{
  --test-vars: fixed;
}

#test {
  position: var(--test-vars);
}
```